# Post-commit script ( hook ) does not getting triggred after a commit Git

Tags: git, jenkins

I'm facing some strange problems since a couple of days. Well, I'm trying to fire a Jenkins build when a commit is done using a post-commit script.

The post-commit script contains one line :

```
#!/bin/sh
"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\curl.exe" 
    "http://xxxxx:8080/git/notifyCommit?url=//xxxxx/Git-repositories$/tetrafx.git"
```

The fact is that this script is never triggered after a commit. I tried to log in a file but no file is created either.

When I run the cmd from a windows console , it works perfectly.

I checked out the permission of the file but nothing supecisous on that.

I'm commiting files from my computer on a shared directory of a windows server (xxxxx). The Jenkins and git repository are on the same server ( xxxxx).

Here is a schema to describe what I do exactly

[image: Process]

Do you have any proposition ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try running the script manually?  Was it working?

Comment: yes :) works fine manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to execute a exe from bash?

Use the `curl` as is in the script:

```
#!/bin/sh
curl http://xxxxx:8080/git/notifyCommit?url=//xxxxx/Git-repositories$/tetrafx.git
```

As simple as that.

As you can see its working : curl google (source + output)

- Small window - source
- Main window - output

[image]

Comment: I have tried this in the first place, but same result ! By the way, I did not understand how it works. This is a bash script executed by windows ? so how ? and even if I use curl as is, it refer to curl.exe stored in /bin directory of my git installation.

Comment: Who is executing the script itself? whicj program

Comment: ok fine about that :) I did not expect that a bash script is working on windows. But as I said, my first try was to execute with curl command and it is not working. The post-commit file is never triggred. And it works nice when I run the command from the windows console.

Comment: So the story of which program is running the script is confusing for me. Like I said, I'm commiting files from my computer to the shared repository. Then I do not have an idea how it works. I thought that git is smart enough to detect that there is a hook script and to execute it. I have allowed all permission for all users to this file

Comment: I know how it works and ill guide you what to do. lets go step by step. 
First of all set the code as i showed you in the script. To verify if the script is called add this as the first line before the curl `echo 'in script:....'` and check your output to see if its getting printed

Comment: ok thanks a lot :). Modification is done, but how I'm suppose to see the echo 'in script' ? For example, I'm using smartGit tool to commit on my machine. So when I commit files, I did not have any verbose outpoot. C:\Users\hfeki\workspaceCleanTetra\TetraFx> git.exe add --force -- pom.xml
C:\Users\hfeki\workspaceCleanTetra\TetraFx> git.exe commit --file=C:\Users\hfeki\AppData\Local\Temp\smartgit6907110805143845876tmp\commit8315448679560007520.tmp -o -- pom.xml
[develop ded9334] test for automatic run test when commiting 12
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)

Comment: Finally resolved. In fact, I wrote the same script in the post-recieve file, and when I commit + push my changes, the Jenkins job is trigerred.

Comment: Cool. glad to help